# inverse of an number column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database column with numbers like 5,10,-2,-8,0.
i need to convert all negative numbers to positive and positive numbers into negative. For example, if I have a positive number like 1 , 5 , 6  then i need to get -1 , -5 , -6 also -4 , -8 , -6 to 4 , 8 , 6.

means inverse of particular number column

```
|Discount|
| ====== |
|   -10  |
|    19  |
|    26  |
|    0   |
|   -22  |
|   -40  |


Desired out put 


|Discount|
| ====== |
|    10  |
|   -19  |
|   -26  |
|    0   |
|    22  |
|    40  |
```

Answer (score 2):

Then just multiply by -1 to switch signs

```
SELECT Discount * -1 as Discount
FROM table
```

For UPDATES

```
UPDATE Discount = Discount * -1
from TABLE
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong for MySQL. You can check it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

You just have to multiply the column discount by -1. The next statement achieve that:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Discount = -Discount
```